# Meteor with external MongoDB (Windows)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, environment-variables

Hi we would like to use an external mongoDB with our meteor project.

On linux we simply:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/our_db_name
```

and it works!

But we cant really figure out how to do so in windows (env variable didn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 set MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/our_db_name
```